# How to connect and Retrieve Snowflake(database) via RestAPi from Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apex, rest

We need to connect to the Snowflake database and get the results when executing LWC component(APEX/JSON). In that LWC when users search some Accounts name, then need to retrieve the Accounts list from the Snowflake database as well if exits. So is there any way to connect snowflake via Rest API with Salesforce to do the above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has a built-in Snowflake connector. Using this method requires you to install the official Salesforce Snowflake connector and then log in using your Snowflake credentials to transfer your Snowflake data objects to Salesforce seamlessly.

Comment: I have gone through the Salesforce connectors. I didn't find other than this snoflek connector which is used in analytics. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_integrate_connectors_snowflake_settings.htm&type=5

This won't satisfy my need. Could you please share a link if you have seen.. Thank you

Comment: This may help: https://hevodata.com/learn/snowflake-to-salesforce/

Comment: @lochana did you try using SQL API of snowflake. I am facing one issue there